# HTML: Can not display image file in subfolder of subfolder (tricky)

Tags: html, image, netbeans, path, subdirectory

I am adding an image in my html file, but with that way

```
<img src="/img/logo/logo_500x150.png" class="logo" alt="Logo 500x150"/>
```

the webpage just show the "missing image" picture.

If I move the image to its parent subfolder, then everything works:

```
<img src="/img/logo_500x150.png" class="logo" alt="Logo 500x150"/>
```

Notes:

1. the folder structure is:

   ```
   web/
       myfile.html
       img/
           logo/
   ```
2. in both ways, when I am at the editor and ctrl+clicking the links, they are showing the image

How can I resolve this to show images properly?

Answer (score 1):

if *web* is a public directory like www.somedomain.com/web

You can use

```
<img src="/web/img/logo/logo_500x150.png" class="logo" alt="Logo 500x150"/>
```

or

```
<img src="img/logo/logo_500x150.png" class="logo" alt="Logo 500x150"/>
```

Comment: what i am saying is that in the first case that you mentioned, it works only if i put the logo image under img folder.

Answer (score 0):

Image is located in the folder one level up from the current folder. Try img src=“../img/logo/

Comment: no its not. I edited the question to be more clearer!

Comment: What error message does the console show when the image is not found?